# How do you fill in an empty data frame based on an index in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, matrix, operation

I'm trying to create an empty data frame then have it filled in based on this for loop.

I want to have a data frame by the dimensions 5x10, which contains the result of the multiplication of the each number in the vectors A and B.

This what I want the end data frame to look like.

[image: This what I want the end data frame to look like.]

So far I'm using a for loop to calculate the product of the 2 vectors but I am not able to insert the result I want into the data frame.

Where am I going wrong?

My Code:

```
a <- c(1:10)
b <- c(1:5)

#Make a dummy dataframe filled with zeros, thats length(a) long and length(b) high     
dummy <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol=5, nrow=10))

heatmap_prep <- function(vector_a,vector_b){
        for (i in 1:length(a)){
            first_number <- a[i]
        for(j in 1:length(b)){
            second_number <- b[j]
            result <- first_number*second_number
            dummy [i,j] <- result
            print(result)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions don't modify things outside of the function. You should create `dummy` inside the function, and `return` the final modified version at the end of your function:

```
heatmap_prep <- function(vector_a,vector_b){
    dummy <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol=length(vector_b), nrow=length(vector_a)))
    for (i in 1:length(a)){
        first_number <- a[i]
        for(j in 1:length(b)){
            second_number <- b[j]
            result <- first_number*second_number
            dummy [i,j] <- result
            print(result)
        }
    }
    return(dummy)
}
heatmap_prep(a, b)
#    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
# 1   1  2  3  4  5
# 2   2  4  6  8 10
# 3   3  6  9 12 15
# 4   4  8 12 16 20
# 5   5 10 15 20 25
# 6   6 12 18 24 30
# 7   7 14 21 28 35
# 8   8 16 24 32 40
# 9   9 18 27 36 45
# 10 10 20 30 40 50
```

However, in this case the built-in `outer` function is much more succinct. The output is a `matrix`, but you can easily coerce it to a `data.frame`.

```
outer(a, b)
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#  [1,]    1    2    3    4    5
#  [2,]    2    4    6    8   10
#  [3,]    3    6    9   12   15
#  [4,]    4    8   12   16   20
#  [5,]    5   10   15   20   25
#  [6,]    6   12   18   24   30
#  [7,]    7   14   21   28   35
#  [8,]    8   16   24   32   40
#  [9,]    9   18   27   36   45
# [10,]   10   20   30   40   50
```

You can also think of this problem as matrix multiplication. This will give the same result.

```
 a %*% t(b)
```